# localhost ansible playbook error - "Failed to update apt cache: unknown reason"

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to install a basic apache2 on a Ubuntu Server localhost, upon running the playbook I got this specific error message:

```
PLAY [Ansible Playbook to Install and Setup Apache on Ubuntu] *******************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Install latest version of Apache] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to update apt cache: unknown reason"}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

On the main playbook, the hosts variable was already set to "localhost". I have no idea I already tried using these two commands and none of them work.

- ansible-playbook playbook.yml --connection=local
- ansible-playbook playbook.yml

Just to add, here's the verbose message:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "allow_change_held_packages": false,
            "allow_downgrade": false,
            "allow_unauthenticated": false,
            "autoclean": false,
            "autoremove": false,
            "cache_valid_time": 0,
            "clean": false,
            "deb": null,
            "default_release": null,
            "dpkg_options": "force-confdef,force-confold",
            "fail_on_autoremove": false,
            "force": false,
            "force_apt_get": false,
            "install_recommends": null,
            "lock_timeout": 60,
            "name": "apache2",
            "only_upgrade": false,
            "package": [
                "apache2"
            ],
            "policy_rc_d": null,
            "purge": false,
            "state": "latest",
            "update_cache": true,
            "update_cache_retries": 5,
            "update_cache_retry_max_delay": 12,
            "upgrade": null
        }
    },
    "msg": "Failed to update apt cache: unknown reason"
}
```

Comment: I would try to `apt-get update` on the node returning that error. While we don't know much about what's going on yet, the "failed to update apt cache" suggests ansible was not yet installing your package. You should be able to reproduce, trying to refresh cache yourself.

Comment: I already did that, however I still get the same issue

Comment: then try to raise verbosity: `ansible-playbook -vvv <playbook>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are encountering the same issue as mine, run apt update. Check if you have errors like if the gpg keys are missing. Import the keys are run apt update again, this fixed my issue.